# Change QTableWidget Header Labels using a QLineEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

So i've made a Table in QtDesigner and i want to use a QLineEdit.text() to name its headers.

The QLineEdit will be respresented with square brackets [].
the QPushButton Will be represented with curly brackets{}.

Column name: [`placeholdertext`                  ] {`Name`}

I am using a `QspinBox` for the indexes.

Now what i want, is to `give the user the possibility of naming all columns` simply `by typing` `[First_name, Last_name, Id_Number, ...]`but `i dont know how to name the headers` neither how to use the `split` thing

How can i make this happen ?

**Update :**

[image]

```
def NameHeaders(self):
    colpos = self.ColumnSpinBox.value()
    colname = self.nameColumnLineEdit.text()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    model.setVerticalHeaderLabels(colname, split(","))
    self.TableWidget.setModel(model)
```

this is the function i've created linked to

```
"Name column/Row" Button
```

(for now it focuses only on naming the columns not the rows),

so what i want is to name the columns just by typing in the column QlineEdit something like : First_name, Last_name, Id_number, ...

and i want the code to detect the text between commas and assign each text to the the value of the QSpinBox

Example :

```
QSpinBoxValue: 2 || Column name : First_name, Last_name, id_number


On_Click 'Name Column/Row' Button: 


assign First_name to Header with index 0


assign Last_name to header with index 1


assign Id_Number to header with index 2
```

is my example clear?

Comment: you could explain me better, your description is unclear, maybe with an image of what you want to obtain, and the code you have until now we would understand you better.

Comment: Sure, give me a minute

Comment: i have edited my code !

Comment: Are you using QTableView or QTableWidget?

Comment: no QTableWidget, the SpinBoxes on the top are for creating the Table, once the QTableWidget is created the those spinboxes the program disables them

Comment: `model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    model.setVerticalHeaderLabels(colname, split(","))
    self.TableWidget.setModel(model)` and why do you use a model? QTableWidget does not allow to establish a model.

Comment: that's why i'm here, i need help and guidance;

Comment: okay, What is the QSpinBox for? Does it only indicate the number of words between commas?

Comment: you say: *assign each text to the the value of the QSpinBox*, QSpinBox only supports numbers, the texts can not be assigned unless they represent numbers.

Comment: it's for indexes,  i use it to let the program know how many columns i'm trying to name ( if the value is 2,  it means name the columns with index0, index1, index2) if that makes sense (a for loop will help here)

Comment: Okay, but it seems weird since the QSpinBox is typically to get user input, not to show outputs but anyway I'll show you how to do it, on the other hand let's say that the table has 3 columns and the user places 4 words. happen? Should you limit yourself to only 3 words or discard the fourth word?

Comment: i think it'll be better to add the column for him, but no, limit myself to only 3 words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to update the `QSpinBox` with the number of words between commas the first thing is to use the `textChanged` signal of `QLineEdit` so that it notifies each time that text is changed, separate the words, count them and update the `QSpinBox`. To set the text in the headers you must use `setHorizontalHeaderLabels()`, but before that you must change the number of columns if necessary.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table_widget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 6)
        self.spinbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le.textChanged.connect(self.on_textChanged)
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change")
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        hlay.addWidget(self.le)
        hlay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.table_widget)
        lay.addLayout(hlay)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_textChanged(self, text):
        words = text.split(",")
        n_words = len(words)
        self.spinbox.setValue(n_words)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        words = self.le.text().split(",")
        n_words = len(words)
        if n_words > self.table_widget.columnCount():
            self.table_widget.setColumnCount(n_words)
        self.table_widget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: but if i want to name the rows all i have to do is to follow the same logic right ?

Comment: @user10567350 yes, it is the same logic.